# PowerBI/DAX Calculating Incorrectly

Tags: powerbi, dax

I crossposted a similiar question on MrExcel - but no reply so asking here hoping theres an answer.

May not be advanced for some of you, but to me it is :)

I have an CalendarAuto() Date Table created, and a table called Staff.

The Staff Table contains columns "Unique ID", "Current Employment: Start Date", "End Date".

I am trying to be able to work out - How Many people employed on xx date. (For this example lets say "31/10/2022")

When I use this DAX code, hijacked and amended slightly from another site (https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Quick-Measures-Gallery/Open-Tickets/m-p/409364).. I get an incorrect answer.

It seems (for lack of a better way to describe it) that its counting the people who started their employment on the filtered date. Instead of how many were employed overall on that date. I have tried a few other methods, all resulting in the same error. This leads me to believe theres something fundamentally flawed with the dates/relationships etc. For good measure I stripped all the useless bits out and created a completely new file, but got the same result.

Any suggestions on fixing this?

```
Employed Staff Count = 
VAR tmpTickets = ADDCOLUMNS('STAFFMASTER',"Effective Date",IF(ISBLANK([End Date]),TODAY(),[End Date]))
VAR tmpTable =  
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
        GENERATE(
            tmpTickets,
            'Calendar'
        ),
        [Date] >= [Current Employment: Start Date] &&
        [Date] <= [Effective Date]
    ),
    "ID",[Unique Id],
    "Date",[Date]
)
VAR tmpTable1 = GROUPBY(tmpTable,[ID],"Count",COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(),[Date]))
RETURN COUNTROWS(tmpTable1)
```

In the examnple above, I expected it to find the amount of people who were employed on a set date, instead its finding the people who started on that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a relationship between `'Calendar'[Date]` 1-* `'STAFFMASTER'[Current Employment: Start Date]`, then you could simply have:

```
Employed Staff Count = 
  var minD = MIN('Calendar'[Date])
  var maxD = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('STAFFMASTER'[Unique ID]),
    'STAFFMASTER'[Current Employment: Start Date] <= minD &&
    ( 'STAFFMASTER'[End Date] >= maxD || ISBLANK('STAFFMASTER'[End Date]) ),
    CROSSFILTER('Calendar'[Date], STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date], None)
  )
```

And if you don't have a relationship then your can remove `, CROSSFILTER(...)` part.

Comment: Thanks Sam, that appears to work perfectly. I'll do a few specific date checks to double check this but on the surface based on the sample date I had, it works exactly right. Is there any reason this works perfect but the other option doesnt (and neither do any of the obvious things available to hijack on many other sites). For example the code I used, gave me a result of 12 for the 31/10/22, which is the number who started on that day, but the correct answer is 1789 which is how many were employed on that day. Your option gives me 1789 :D

Comment: Most probable the other solutions do not remove the relationship.